# insert ajax response in data table

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, html-table

I need to insert a AJAX response data in Data table. I am getting the AJAX response and on the success of the AJAX i need to insert the response data in data table.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "macrocall.cgi",
    data: { macro:"loadcase_ajax",CGISESSID:$CGISESSID,ph_name:phase_name},
    dataType: 'text',
    success:function (data) 
            {       
                var return_data=data;
                alert("return data"+return_data);
            }
   });
```

This is the return data format.

```
return data**~93~ARRIAE~BETEA~FRONT_IMPACT~FL 1 - 48 Kmph ~../macro/1176/images/FL1.jpg**
```

And my HTML looks like,

```
<html>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="display"
    id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #336699;">
            <th><font color="#fff">SNO</font></th>
            <th><font color="#fff">TESTG PHASE</font></th>
            <th><font color="#fff">PROJECT NAME</font></th>
            <th><font color="#fff">IMPACT</font></th>
            <th><font color="#fff">LOADCE</font></th>
            <th><font color="#fff">IMAGE</font></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Response values to be inserted here</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Please Suggest how it can be done .. the above table is a data table.

Comment: i have tried inserting it using the for loop structure by creating a td run time and appending it to the table. this thing works but the data table doesn't  function .. the data doesnot get inserted in the data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot obtain your data in a better format from your server/datasource, you'll have to:

1. Parse the data yourself into a usable format. I did this by removing first the `data**` prefix and `**` suffix, then creating an array of values by splitting the string using the `~` as the delimiter. The data is then stored in an array.
2. Looping through the dataset, prepare the HTML for the table rows with corresponding data. For extra credit, I added a check in the loop to see if the value had `/image/` in the string, suggesting that it is a path instead of simply a value.
3. Insert the values into the table.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/at9ug0db/)

Answer (score 0):

1 - First, try changing the `dataType` to `'json'`

2 - In your ActionClass which variable name used. `example : private ProjectInfo variable_name;`

3 - Check that the returned data format looks like this:

`{"variable_name" : ["93", "ARRIAE","BETE","FRONT_IMPACT","FL 1 - 48  kmph","../macro/1176/images/FL1.jpg"]};`

4 - Now append the data into your table.

`for(i=0;i<data.variable_name.length;i++){
    $('<tr>"+data.variable_name[i]+"</tr>').appendTo('table > tbody');
 }`